# react swipeable tabs from material ui issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui, react-component

I'm facing a problem in my application with the react swipeable tabs from material-ui. I installed and did everything recommended on the documentation.
Right now, I'm getting the following error showed on the screenshot. Is there any problem incorporating **Swipeable tabs** from material ui. Because when I'm using the controlled example it's working fine with showing no errors.

[image]

**Currently I'm working with the following code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Tabs, Tab} from 'material-ui/Tabs';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';

const styles = {
  headline: {
    fontSize: 24,
    paddingTop: 16,
    marginBottom: 12,
    fontWeight: 400,
  },
  slide: {
    padding: 10,
  },
};

export default class ProfileTabSection extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          slideIndex: 0,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({
            slideIndex: value,
        });
    };


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <div className="container-fluid profile-tab-section">
                    <Tabs 
                        onChange={this.handleTabChange}
                        value={this.state.slideIndex}
                    >
                        <Tab label="Feed" value={0} />
                        <Tab label="All posts" value={1} />
                        <Tab label="Followers" value={2} />
                        <Tab label="Following" value={3} />
                    </Tabs>
                    <SwipeableViews
                      index={this.state.slideIndex}
                      onChangeIndex={this.handleChange}
                    >
                        <div id="feed_slide">
                          It's a feed slide                         </div>
                        <div id="all_posts_slide" style={styles.slide}>
                            It's an all posts slide!
                        </div>
                        <div id="followers_slide" style={styles.slide}>
                          Followers
                        </div>
                        <div id="following_slide" style={styles.slide}>
                          Following
                        </div>
                    </SwipeableViews>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` should do the trick

Comment: applied that but still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should be enclosing your code in

import following statements

```
 import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
 import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
```

later enclose your Material-ui components between following code

```
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>

    </ MuiThemeProvider>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. Remove `package-lock.json` and/or `yarn.lock`,
2. `rm -rf node_modules`,
3. Run `npm install` (or `yarn install` if you are using `yarn`), and
4. `npm start` again.

If this doesn't work, share your `package.json`